# Windows Networking continuously drops computers in Network Neighborhood

Tags: networking, samba

My Windows 10 PC is networked to 4 other PCs in my lab. It drops all of them constantly. On boot they are all showing, but if I go back later during the day the host PC is the only one showing. I have Samba configured on my PC & I can access all of the PCs via SSH. the other PCs see Windows 10 & do not drop it (2 Linux, 1 Win 7, & 1 Win 10). I have double checked that that sharing is ticked & all PCs are in the same workgroup. It's an intermittent issue. I have added all my PCs to the host file with the correct IP address & on reboot everything comes back. Later on I go back to file explorer & they're all gone again. It's more an annoyance than a problem but any insight would be greatly appreciated. How can I fix this?

Comment: Having had a similar issue, I've found that double-clicking a shortcut with the full UNC path [\\host\share_name\path] helps Windows find the connection after it has been lost. Not an answer, just a work-around that does not fix the issue.

Comment: Are they all on the same IP subnet on the same wired Ethernet LAN? If not, please edit your Question to include network details.